# What is q-linear embedding?

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields, extension-field

Let h be a non-negative integer and f: $F_{q^k}$->$F_{q^{k+h}}$ be a q-linear embedding. Then $a_tf(x^{q^t})+a_{t-1}f(x^{q^{t-1}})+...+a_0f(x)$ is a q-linear mapping from
$F_{q^k}$ to $F_{q^{k+h}}$.

Questions:

1. What is q-linear embedding? I know in the field extension, embedding
   a field A to B means extend A by adjoining elements to B?
2. How to understand the q-linear mapping?

Comment: Are the $a_k\in F_q$?

Comment: Linear just means a linear transformation between two vector spaces over the field of $q$ elements.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  I was wondering whether a rival definition could be $f(x^q)= f (x)^q$ (which would make sense, in characteristic $p$). Laura, can you give the reference?

Comment: @peterag $a_i$ is in $F_q^{k+h}$ for i=0,1,...,t.

Comment: In which case, my guess (as given to Gerry) makes no sense.

Comment: My somewhat educated guess would be that *a $q$-linear embedding* is simply an injective function from $\Bbb{F}_{q^k}$ to $\Bbb{F}_{q^{k+h}}$ that also happens to be linear over the subfield $\Bbb{F}_q$. Because $x\mapsto x^{q^i}$ is also linear over $\Bbb{F}_q$, the compositions $f(x^{q^i})$ are so also. For all $i$. A linear combination of $\Bbb{F}_q$-linear transformations is also $\Bbb{F}_q$-linear. The coefficients $a_j$ apparently reside inside $\Bbb{F}_{q^{k+h}}$ for otherwise the multiplications on the codomain side make no sense. Anyway, that is still linear over the small field.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen f is a mapping from $F_q^{k}$ to $F_q^{k+h}$, why in the formula $a_tf(x^{q^t})...$, the domain is a q-ploy?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, Laura? The rule is about describing the image of an element $x\in\Bbb{F}_{q^k}$. This is different from $\Bbb{F}_q^k$. The elements of the former come from an extension field, but the elements of the latter are $k$-tuples of elements from $\Bbb{F}_q$. Raising to powers of $q$ is only interesting for elements of the extension field, not for vectors.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Sorry, I made a writing mistake. It supposes to "from $F_{q^{k}}$ to $F_{q^{k+h}}$". Actually, I don't understand what $f$ looks like because I don't very well understand in what is "embedding" means. For example, define f: $F_{2}$->$F_{2^2}$ be a q-linear embedding described above, then f could be $x^2+x+1$, then $f(x^{2^t})=(x^{2^t})^2+(x^{2^t})+1$. Is that right to understand it? If not, can you give me examples? Thank you

Comment: Laura, that's about it, I think. I will post a proper answer later. I need to write the scripts for a few "remote lectures" for tomorrow, and then record them. Pandemic.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Ok, thanks a lots

Answer (score 0):

The elements here seem to be:

- A (fixed) $\Bbb{F}_q$-linear mapping $f:\Bbb{F}_{q^k}\to\Bbb{F}_{q^{k+h}}$. This is just a linear transformation from a $k$-dimensional space to a $(k+h)$-dimensional space. Observe that in general $\Bbb{F}_{q^k}$ is not a subfield of $\Bbb{F}_{q^{k+h}}$, so there is no natural embedding available. We simply fix some linear transformation with a trivial kernel (to make it injective). The mapping $f$ is not an *embedding of fields* in the sense that it does not preservec products, it is an embedding of vector spaces such that the vector spaces happen to be fields. That may sound like splitting hairs, but we cannot guarantee that this would be an embedding of fields in the natural sense, and that confuses many readers of your question.
- The Frobenius automorphism $\phi:x\mapsto x^q$ of the domain $\Bbb{F}_{q^k}$. It is also $\Bbb{F}_q$-linear. Hence so are its compositions with itself $\phi\circ\cdots\circ\phi:x\mapsto x^{q^i}$, $i$ some natural number. And the compositions of iterates of $\phi$ and $f$, $x\mapsto f(x^{q^i})$. These latter mappings have $\Bbb{F}_{q^{k+h}}$ as their domain.
- The mappings $y\mapsto ay$ from $\Bbb{F}_{q^{k+h}}$ to itself. Here $a$ is a constant from the field $\Bbb{F}_{q^{k+h}}$, and this is just multiplication in that field. The distributivity law then gives immediately that these mappings are linear over the small field $\Bbb{F}_q$.
- Consequently a mapping of the form $x\mapsto af(x^{q^i})$ is an $\Bbb{F}_q$-linear transformation from $\Bbb{F}_{q^k}$ to $\Bbb{F}_{q^{k+h}}$ as a composition of such.

A mapping of the form
$$x\mapsto \sum_{i=0}^ta_i f(x^{q^i})$$
is thus $\Bbb{F}_q$-linear as a sum of such.

---

As a smallest example consider the case $q=2$, $k=2$, $h=1$. The domain is the field $\Bbb{F}_4$ that is a vector space over $\Bbb{F}_2$ with basis $\{1,\alpha\}$, where $\alpha$ satisfies the equation $\alpha^2=\alpha+1$ (which pretty much defines the multiplication in $\Bbb{F}_4$). The codomain is the field $\Bbb{F}_8$ which we can think of as a 3-dimensional vector space over $\Bbb{F}_2$ with a basis $\{1,\beta,\beta^2\}$, with the multiplication determined by $\beta^3=\beta+1$.

In this toy example we can use (for example)
$$f:\Bbb{F}_4\to\Bbb{F}_8, a_0+a_1\alpha\mapsto a_0+a_1\beta^2$$
as an $\Bbb{F}_2$-linear "embedding". After all, this obviously has a trivial kernel, so it is an embedding of vector spaces. The linear transformations your source seems to be describing are sums of mappings like
$$
x\mapsto \beta f(x^2).
$$
With the chosen $f$ we would get
$$
\begin{aligned}
a_0+a_1\alpha&\mapsto \beta f(a_0+a_1\alpha^2)\\
&=\beta f(a_0+a_1(1+\alpha))\\
&=\beta f([a_0+a_1]+a_1\alpha)\\
&=\beta([a_0+a_1]f(1)+a_1 f(\alpha))\\
&=\beta(a_0+a_1)+\beta^3a_1\\
&=\beta(a_0+a_1)+(1+\beta)a_1\\
&=a_1+a_0\beta,
\end{aligned}
$$
making it plain that this mapping is $\Bbb{F}_2$-linear.